# c++ templates and overloading operators

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I am trying to understand how this program works. i am new to c++ templates.
Can someone explain why we need the following function?

```
friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Temp &temp)
```

It seems to work only for the string template.

Also, what does the function `operator T() {return val;}` do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

template <typename T>
class Temp {        
    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Temp &temp) {
    os << temp.val;
    return os;
    }

public:
    Temp(T val) : val(val) {}
    operator T() {return val;}
public:
    T val;
};
```

usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

#include "temp2.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    temp<int> si = 10;
    cout << "si: " << si << endl;
    si = si + 2;
    cout << "After si = si + 2: " << si << endl;

    Temp<double> si2 = 15.5;
    cout << "si: " << si2 << endl;
    si2 = si2 + 2.3;
    cout << "After si = si + 2: " << si2 << endl;

    Temp<string> ss = string("Hello");
    cout << "ss: " << ss << endl;
    ss = string(ss).substr(1);
    cout << "After ss = si.substr(1): " << ss << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: no error just trying to understand the program

Comment: what does it say when the string is not the template arguement, "seems to work only for the string template"

Comment: @KarishKarish: From where did you get this source code?

Comment: @111111 i mean it used only with the string template, Temp<double>, and Temp<int> dont use this function

Comment: @KarishKarish you are mistaken : both `si` and `si2` variables are using the operator.

Comment: I'm rather aloof with the `operator T()`, especially if T is ever a CV. Rather, I would use `operator const T&() const`, but to each their own.

Comment: It amazes me that students don't actually write code to try things out any more - If you want to know what the operator T() does try it out. If you don't know how to call it then google, and if that fails ask for help...

Comment: @WhozCraig if you add a `const` or `&` qualifier to the template parameter somewhere in the template body, then you cannot use a type with those attributes anymore as a parameter for the template, or you have to include some extensive testing to remove the attributes from the type etc.

Comment: @didierc Kinda got lost on that.  I think it would be a lot easier to simply cite and example. You mean the template parameter type can't be something like `MyClass<int&>`, where the internal var is a T-ref rather than a T?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, I think that the compiler would choke on a `const const string &` for instance, if you pass `const string` as your parameter, and you have your cast operator implemented there as well.

Comment: @didierc no question about it. The same is true if you try and have a std::vector<int&>, a std::vector<const int> etc. I always apply such modifiers to my *member* rather than the template parameter. I.e. my memvar would be `const T& var;` or `T& var;`, etc. I've not had a reason yet to do it at the template parameter location yet, but if someone can proffer up a good reason to *that compiles with the std lib* I'm all ears.

Comment: @WhozCraig I meant only in that template. Your code is perfectly ok otherwise. It actually make a lot of sense to have a cast operator like the one you wrote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the operator `<<` is really needed, but it's convenient to have it when using output streams. Also, the operator needs to access the inner value of the Temp class, hence the `friend` qualifier. Without it, the class would have to expose the inner value `val` to the external world somehow (the usual way is to make a public read only method), and this create a maintenance problem, since future evolutions of the class would have to keep supporting the method, even if the class internals change.

In other words, having the `<<` operator declared as friend to the class prevents the implementation details to leak out to the rest of the world.

That said, the T() operator provides almost the service of the hypothetic read only method that I described above, but with replacing the read only part by copying the `val` field. Basically, it's a cast operator allowing to implicitely cast a Temp value to a T value. The `<<` operator could have been implemented using that cast operator, and thus without the need of the friend qualifier. However, certainly for efficiency concerns, the friend qualifier has been kept to avoid the overhead of copying `val`.

Regarding the implementation of the `<<` operator, we can see that it rely on the same operator defined for the T typename. Any type having this operator defined for should work without problem with this template.